# make first values positive in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've got the following list of tuples:

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (1, -3), (1, -4), (0, -4), (0, -3), (-1, -3), (-2, -3), (-2, -2), (-2, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (0, -2)]
```

And I want the following:

```
>>> addvalues(list_of_tuples)
[(2, 0), (2, -1), (3, -1), (3, -2), (3, -3), (3, -4), (2, -4), (2, -3), (1, -3), (0, -3), (0, -2), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (2, -2)]
#original
>>> list_of_tuples
[(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (1, -3), (1, -4), (0, -4), (0, -3), (-1, -3), (-2, -3), (-2, -2), (-2, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (0, -2)]
```

for tuple in list_of_tuples the lowest value in tuple[0] is -2 and I want to add a value to every tuple[0] until the lowest value is 0, how do you do that? (In general the lowest value doesn't need to be -2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a nicer way of doing it, but this works. Find the smallest item. If it is less than 0, add it to the first item in each tuple.

```
list_of_tuples = [(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (1, -3), (1, -4), (0, -4), (0, -3), (-1, -3), (-2, -3), (-2, -2), (-2, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (0, -2)]
to_add = min(list_of_tuples)[0]
if to_add < 0:
    list_of_tuples = [(a[0]-to_add, a[1]) for a in list_of_tuples]

# [(2, 0), (2, -1), (3, -1), (3, -2), (3, -3), (3, -4), (2, -4), (2, -3), (1, -3), (0, -3), (0, -2), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (2, -2)]
```

Comment: This would work but why sort the whole thing when you need the minimum? `min(i[0] for i in list_of_tuples)` is more pythonic.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that handles the case where there may be no tuples with negative values

Comment: @ktdrv: python already sorts on the first index, so you can just use `min(list_of_tuples)[0]`, which looks even more pythonic to me.

Comment: @BrtH: Valid point but it is a little less clear, you'll have to agree. Especially for someone who finds themselves asking the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
to_add = 0 - min(list_of_tuples)[0]
new_list = [(i[0] + to_add, i[1]) for i in list_of_tuples]
```

Comment: that could get ugly if there are no negatives . . .

Comment: @ernie: No, it won't. Let's say that the lowest is 2. In order for the lowest value to be 0, you have to subtract 2. This is exactly what my code does, and there is no problem that it's not negative.

Comment: I read the question title, which suggests increasing the min.  The question seems to imply baselining to 0, and if that's correct, your solution is good.  Meh for ambiguous criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :-

```
list_of_tuples = [(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (1, -3), (1, -4), (0, -4), (0, -3), (-1, -3), (-2, -3), (-2, -2), (-2, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (0, -2)]

# get the min of x
minx = min(x for x, y in list_of_tuples)

# create the new list
new_tuples = [(x - minx, y) for x, y in list_of_tuples]

# do a test
assert new_tuples == [(2, 0), (2, -1), (3, -1), (3, -2), (3, -3), (3, -4), (2, -4), (2, -3), (1, -3), (0, -3), (0, -2), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (2, -2)]
print("Passed")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the minimum and then subtract it.

```
min_ = min(l, key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
```

this way it pass every elemnt to the function "key" first, and then finds the minimum. Since the funcition passed returns the first element of the tuple, you can see why it works. (I showed how to use the key argument; in this case you dont need it because min already checks the first element of the tuple first. but if, say, you wanted to consider the second, or maybe their product, that is the way to go)

to modify the list, if i understood correctly what you want to do, you can do

```
[(x[0] + min_, x[1]) for x in l]
```

this is called list comprehension, it is equivalent to

```
for x in l:
    y = (x[0] + min, x[1])
    new_list.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need something that handles positive/negatives numbers, you could try this. It finds the minimum x value in the list of tuples, and if the value is less than 0, takes the absolute value and increments all numbers by that number. If the minimum number is greater than 0, it increments the numbers by 0 (i.e. does not change anything). The returned result is the updated list of tuples.

```
In [65]: def addvalues(l):
    min_x = min(l, key=lambda x: x[0])[0] # x[1] to work with the second element
    min_x = abs(min_x) if min_x < 0 else 0
    return [tuple((x+min_x, y)) for x, y in l]
   ....:

In [69]: addvalues(list_of_tuples)
Out[69]:
[(2, 0),
 (2, -1),
 (3, -1),
 (3, -2),
 (3, -3),
 (3, -4),
 (2, -4),
 (2, -3),
 (1, -3),
 (0, -3),
 (0, -2),
 (0, -1),
 (1, -1),
 (1, -2),
 (2, -2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In [52]: list_of_tuples = [(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, -2), (1, -3), (1, -4), (0, -4), (0, -3), (-1, -3), (-2, -3), (-2, -2), (-2, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (0, -2)]

In [53]: to_add = min(list_of_tuples, key=operator.itemgetter(0))[0] *-1

In [54]: to_add
Out[54]: 2

In [55]: [tuple([t[0]+2,t[1]]) for t in list_of_tuples]
Out[55]: 
[(2, 0),
 (2, -1),
 (3, -1),
 (3, -2),
 (3, -3),
 (3, -4),
 (2, -4),
 (2, -3),
 (1, -3),
 (0, -3),
 (0, -2),
 (0, -1),
 (1, -1),
 (1, -2),
 (2, -2)]

In [56]: list_of_tuples # input unchanged
Out[56]: 
[(0, 0),
 (0, -1),
 (1, -1),
 (1, -2),
 (1, -3),
 (1, -4),
 (0, -4),
 (0, -3),
 (-1, -3),
 (-2, -3),
 (-2, -2),
 (-2, -1),
 (-1, -1),
 (-1, -2),
 (0, -2)]
```

Hope this helps